# Use exclamation in .gitignore to track something specially?

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is my project folder:

```
aaa
  ├─ bbb.txt
  ├─ ccc.txt
  └─ ddd.txt
.gitignore
```

For my own, I wanna ignore all the files or folders in `aaa` except `bbb.txt`

So, I write the `.gitignore` like this:

```
aaa/
!aaa/bbb.txt
```

But `bbb.txt` is also tracked.

So, could you tell me how to solve this?

**Update:**

After I read the comment and the answer, I begin to understand how to fix this question.

But I come to a new question:

What's the difference between `a/` and `a/*` and `a/**`?

Comment: `aaa/*` instead so that all files and folders except `bbb.txt` in `aaa` will be ignored.

Comment: @ElpieKay What's the difference between `aaa/*` with `aaa/` ?

Comment: `aaa/` matches the directory `aaa` and paths underneath it while `aaa/*` matches paths underneath `aaa` only. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. So if `aaa` itself is excluded, all paths underneath it can't be re-included. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @ElpieKay Wow, thanks. From your description, I can get If I wanna ignore some path except a few files in it, I should use `aaa/*`. Apart from this condition, `aaa/` is equal to `aaa/*`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all files from index by running `git rm -r --cached ./`
then try to update your .gitignore file to

```
aaa/*
!aaa/bbb.txt
```

this will ignore all files under aaa folder except bbb.txt

Comment: What's the difference between `aaa/*` with `aaa/`

Comment: aaa/ will reach only your root tree that contains only aaa/ folder, and aaa/* will reach your files inside aaa/ folder, aaa/ exclude all files under aaa/ folder without any exception, and aaa/* will exclude files that match the * regex expression, and thus will it will look for extra regex expressions that may add an exception for the aaa/ folder like the "!aaa/bbb.txt" in your example.

Comment: I have a new question, the difference between `a/` and `a/*` and `a/**`, could you tell me?

Comment: a/* and a/** are the same, the asterisk indicates zero or more occurrences, so no need to duplicate it.

Comment: wow, maybe they are something different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157448/the-difference-between-a-and-a-and-a-in-gitignore

Comment: in case if you do **.txt it will select all txt files of length two

Comment: There are subtle differences between /* & /**,  the double matches forward slashes. According to the docs >> A trailing "/**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**" matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.

Comment: where a /* >> An asterisk "*" matches anything except a slash. The character "?" matches any one character except "/". The range notation, e.g. [a-zA-Z], can be used to match one of the characters in a range. See fnmatch(3) and the FNM_PATHNAME flag for a more detailed description.

Comment: IDK About windows or unix, but on linux, a slash can be the difference between your project working as expected, and your project being totally busted and not knowing why.