# The difference between a/ and a/* and a/** in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is my file folder.

```
a
├─ b
│  ├─ b1.txt
│  └─ b2.txt
├─ a1.txt
└─ a2.txt
.gitignore
```

**Firstly:**

I found if I wanna ignore the folder a, `a/` and `a/*` and `a/**` all can complete.

**Secondly:**

I wanna ignore all the things in folder `a` except the folder `b`, the only way to do this is:

```
a/*
!a/b/
```

I don't know why `a/**` can't do this?

```
# this way can't except folder b
a/**
!a/b/
```

Or you can tell me how can I use `a/**` ?

Comment: I hope my answer answers your question. If not, please rephrase the question to make clearer what you actual question is. Because I'm not sure what you mean by "why `a/**` can't do this". What is "this" in this context?

Comment: I means that I changed `a/*` to `a/**`, then git still ignore the b folder.

Comment: You mean with `!a/b/` or without `!a/b/`? `a/*` and `a/**` behave exactly the same. `a/**` means ignore every file in every subdirectory recursively. `a/*` means ignore all direct children of `a`. But as this not only works on files but also folders, it is effectively the same as contents of ignored folders are also ignored.

Comment: Oh Sorry make you confused. I means with `!a/b`. I can use `a/*` and `!a/b` to have b folder in git. But with `a/**` and `!a/b` I can't get this. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Ah, well, `a/**` does explicitly ignore all files and folders in `a` recursively down to the bone. Thus it simply will not work to include. You have to use `a/*` as described in my answer to "just" ignore everything in `a` non-recursively which will still be effective recursively, as an excluded folder also excludes all its contents and then you can include `b`. `**` is usually only resonable if followed by something like `a/**/d` to ignore all files and folders name `d` inside `a` and all its subdirectories recursively.

Answer (score 14):

`**` matches any amount of directories, `*` only one.
So if you e. g. ignore `/a/**/d/`, then `/a/b/d/` and `/a/b/c/d/` both are ignored.
If you e. g. ignore `/a/*/d/`, then `/a/b/d/` is ignored while `/a/b/c/d/` is not ignored.

If a folder is ignored, then Git does not even look at its contents to check for inclusions. That is why you cannot ignore `/a/` and then include `/a/b/`, as Git does not even look into `/a/`. Because of this you must instead ignore all contents in `/a/` with `/a/*` and then include `/a/b/` to ignore everything in `/a/`, except all contents of `/a/b/`.

Answer (score 3):

To a first approximation, Git doesn't "do" directories ("folders") at all.

Gitignore files are an exception to this rule, but in a tricky way.

First, Git is mainly about files.  Files are either tracked or untracked.  A file is untracked if and only if it is not *currently* in the index.  Note that Git can read its own index *very quickly*, usually much faster than the underlying operating system can read through directory trees ("folders and subfolders").

Next, `gitignore` rules are mainly about files, since only files can be untracked or become tracked.  When `git status` says that some directory ("folder") is untracked, what it means is that there are one or more untracked *files* contained *within* that directory.  (Using `git add` works similarly, except that instead of "complain about", the action to be taken is "copy into index".)

In order to *find* untracked files, Git would have to open and read *every* directory (or "folder") in your work-tree.  To make Git perform faster, however, Git uses this trick:

- if the path *P* (such as `a` or `a/b`) names a directory, *and*
- if there are no existing *tracked* files whose path *begins with* *P* (followed by a trailing slash; e.g., in this case, there is no `a/b/b1.txt` and no `a/a2.txt` in the index, for instance), *and*
- if path *P* matches an "ignore" rule (without a cancellation for it), *then*

Git skips reading the directory *P* entirely.  It never looks to see if there are any untracked files within it.  It does this because reading directories in Linux (and other OSes) is relatively slow.

So now we come to a pattern like `a/*` or `a/**`, where either `a` is currently not ignored, or there are files in the index whose paths start with `a/`.  In order to decide whether there are files in `a` that are untracked and should be complained-about (if not ignored) or not-complained-about (if ignored), Git *must* read directory `a`.

Having read directory `a`, Git finds that there are two files `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` and a directory `b`.  Assuming `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` are currently untracked, it scans all `.gitignore` patterns to see if those match the two files.  If not, Git complains about them (or adds them to the index).  But `b` is a directory, so the optimization kicks in:

- there are no `b/` paths in the index, *and*
- `b` matches the `a/*` or `a/**` rule

As long as there is no `!a/b` or `!a/b/` rule, Git will ignore directory `a/b` at this point and never look inside it.  It does not matter whether you use `*` or `**`.

Should there be at least one tracked file in the index whose name starts with `a/b/`, however, the optimization fails.  Or, if you override the ignore with `!a/b` or `!a/b/`, the directory itself is not ignored.  In either of these cases, Git reads directory `a/b/`.  Having read the directory, Git will find files `a/b/b1.txt` and `a/b/b2.txt`.  It then checks whether these match a `.gitignore` rule.

As [Vampire noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44157728/1256452), `**` matches *zero or more* directories.  (If the pattern *ends with* `**` it also matches all files in those zero-or-more directories.)  To make this have some action that differs from `a/*`, so that we could see a difference, we would need additional levels of sub-directories (which we would need to force Git to read, either by explicitly un-ignoring at least one such as `a/b/` with `!` rules, or by having tracked files within them).

(In experiments I ran a while ago, I found cases where `**` matches *one or more* directories in Git, instead of *zero or more*.  I think this occurs in pathname expansion, e.g., if you use `git log -- 'a/**/file.txt'` for instance.  So watch out: the ignore rules for `**` matching may differ from other rules.)

Answer (score 0):

try (without `/`):

```
a
!a/b
```

`**` is used in ignoring "in any subdirectory", for example, you have

```
a/b1.txt
a/b/b1.txt
```

you can ignore all `b1.txt` files in any subdirectories with `a/**/b1.txt`

Comment: Your suggestion cannot work. If you ignore `a`, you cannot include `a/b`, because if `a` is ignored Git does not even look inside `a` to see that you unignored `a/b`, just as descirbed in my answer. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire Yep. I just try his answer.. but nothing works.

Comment: you are true, my fault, just checked my old .gitignore file and i am wondering, why it is doing what i need to do